# If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ are two random variables that may or may not be independent, what is $E(XY)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ are two random variables that may or may not be independent, I am wondering what $\operatorname{E}(XY)$ might be. It appears they have the same distribution, but does that imply anything about independence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ is the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, which in this case could be any real number in $[-1,1]$. You can't say anything more based on the information you've given.

Comment: @user321627 To add to this. If $U,V$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$ and $ 0 \leq \rho \leq 1$ and if you define $X = U, Y = \pm \sqrt{\rho} U + \sqrt{1-\rho}V$, then $E(XY) = \pm \sqrt{\rho}$. So all values in $[-1,1]$ can be attained.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri  Can I ask what $Y = \pm \sqrt{\rho} U + \sqrt{1-\rho}V$ is supposed to be and why you used it as a case here? I thought you had meant to say that if $U,V$ are iid $N(0,1)$, then $Y=\rho U +\sqrt{1-\rho^2}V$ is also standard normal but correlated with $U$, but it seems that your $Y$ above has $\pm \sqrt{\rho}$ instead of $\rho$. Thanks!

Comment: There is no essential difference between the two parametrizations, yours is more succint.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that $X$ and $Y$ are both the same random variable, so always equal to each other. In that case $\operatorname{E}(XY) = \operatorname{E}(X^2) = 1.$

If $X\sim N(0,1),$ then $-X\sim N(0,1),$ so one could have $Y$ being $-X$, in which case $\operatorname{E}(XY) = \operatorname{E}(-X^2) = -1.$

Another possibility is that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so $\operatorname{E}(XY) = \operatorname{E}(X)\operatorname{E}(Y) = 0.$

Another is that after observing $X,$ you toss a coin and then decide $Y = X$ or $Y=-X$ according to the outcome. In that case it can be shown that $\operatorname{E}(XY) = 0$ even though $X$ and $Y$ are far from independent.

Another is that $Y=(X+Z)/\sqrt 2$ where $X,Z$ are independent random variables distributed as $N(0,1).$  In that case $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $\operatorname{E}(XY) = 1/\sqrt 2.$

Comment: Your final example $Y=(X+Z)/2$ may need a minor adjustment as I think that has variance $\frac12$ not $1$.  Perhaps $Y=(X+Z)/\sqrt{2}$ in which case $\operatorname{E}(XY) = 1/\sqrt{2}$